# How to set value to NLog.config

Tags: c#, wpf, nlog

I am just wondering how to change the value in **NLog.config** file from other file configuration for example,

`<variable name="logDirectory" value="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}"/>`

I want to change logDirectory value to be "C:/logs/${shortdate}" and of course I want to get the value from other configuration file. Is it possible to do that?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use configSource="YourConfigFile"